# Collapsing NSSplitViewItem does not call splitViewDidResizeSubviews

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nssplitview, nssplitviewcontroller

I have a class that inherits from `NSSplitViewController` and overrides the `splitViewDidResizeSubviews` function.

When I call collapse on a `NSSplitViewItem` inside the `NSSplitViewController` and I see the `NSSplitViewItem` visibly resize the `splitViewDidResizeSubviews` function isn't called.

If I resize the window the `splitViewDidResizeSubviews` function is called so I know it is implemented correctly.

Can I expect the `splitViewDidResizeSubviews` function to be called on a collapse and if so what might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because collapsing splitViewItem doesn't resize its actual frame size but just toggling item's visibility. The splitViewItem holds the frame size if you just toggle `isCollapsed` status.

(An exception is when item expands outward. Namely `splitViewItem.collapseBehavior = .preferResizingSplitViewWithFixedSiblings`. As I tested, it invokes `splitViewDidResizeSubviews`.)

So for such usage I prefer to override another method of NSSplitViewController for instance:

```
func splitView(_ splitView: NSSplitView, shouldCollapseSubview subview: NSView, forDoubleClickOnDividerAt dividerIndex: Int
```

Comment: Unfortunately `shouldCollapseSubview` does not meet my requirements for when I am notified and nor do any of the other methods in `NSSplitViewController` so I just added more logic to the button that invokes the collapse and expand and included a transaction so I know then the animator is finished.